# Will probably or probably will

Tags: modal-verbs, adverbs, word-order

I would like to say that I want to buy something in future, but I'm not sure which of the sentences below is a better choice:

> 1. We **will probably** order another box of earphones, please send us invoice for the order so we can process the payment
> 2. We **probably will** order another box of earphones, please send us invoice for the order so we can process the payment

kindly advise, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Adverbs can be placed in four positions in a sentence:

> 1.At the beginning;
>
> 2.At the end;
>
> 3.After the verb to be and all auxiliary verbs: can, may, will, must, shall etc.
>
> 4.Before all the other verbs.

In case of modal verbs (have, can, will, shall, may, must, might), the adverb follows the verb.

So, the better choice in your example is

> We **will probably** order another box of earphones, please send us invoice for the order so we can process the payment

However, adverbs are also used to put emphasis on a verb , and in that case they come before the verb. So, you may find the second sentence being used in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

it's will probably because it's probably won't and I remembered that it was the oppesit. I'm sorry if my English isn't correct 'cause I'm Dutch.

Comment: Can you give more reasoning as to why the case of ‘probably won’t’ will apply, other than ‘they’re opposite’?